# Eclipse Keyboard shortcuts in Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos

I'm running Leopard and do all my Java development in eclipse. Some of the shortcuts work such as Command-1 which will do a quick suggest. However how do I get the Function Keys (F5 for refresh in the package explorer) to work? Right now it brings up spaces or whatever System Preferences maps to that.

What about Control-click into a breakpoint when I'm debugging and want to go directly to the chosen function? Is there a way for my eclipse keyboard shortcuts to take precedence over other programs?

i'm running eclipse 3.4 though I've had this problem since eclipse 3.2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Its been a while since I used eclipse on the mac but I think you have to go to Preferences.app and check the "keyboard" pane. There should be an option that chooses if its  <kbd>Fn</kbd>-function-key or just function-key for the key press. After that, it would be  <kbd>Fn+F5</kbd> for expose and just  <kbd>F5</kbd> for  <kbd>F5</kbd>. You will lose the ability to dim the screen and adjust the sound from the keyboard.

Answer (score 11):

In system preferences under keyboard there is a toggle to turn the f keys into real function keys

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a macbook? In OO.org at least, you have to press fn-fx to get at the application short-cut, otherwise you get the system-wide one.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with an external keyboard that don't have the fn key?

Comment: It depends, if your keyboard has mac support, there may be an alternative key to fn. Failing that, you might be able to turn off the fx key special function all together (vol control, brightness, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like an Eclipse problem.

Are you using an External Keyboard or a macbook ?

If you want to use the debuggers and stuff, you need to change the interpretation of the function keys. You have to manually hit the FN key on your laptop keyboard. Some external keyboards have a function lock.

Comment: Or you can go into System Preferences -> Keyboard and untick "Use all F1, F2, etc keys as standard function keys".  Then it's the opposite: you need to press fn + the function key to get the Mac-behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can change system level default behaviour from preferences as @sorin explained. A correction to the claim in the last sentence, 
"You can use <kbd>Fn</kbd>-function-key to dim the screen and adjust the sound from the keyboard."

Answer (score 0):

for making function keys work for external keyboards by default (and not having to push the extra fn key):

Change the default function key behavior
Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences.
Click Keyboard.
Select "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys on external keyboards".